# Insert Mode Arrow Keys

Tags: neovim, init.lua

I really like Neovim to take notes but there are a lot of friction points when you stay a long time in insert mode.. Anyway, the current problem is that I can't jump lines like in normal mode...

I want to move it like this `gj` or `gk` instead of `h,j,k,l` but in INSERTMODE !

I tried this:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("i", "<Up>", "<ESC>gki", {})

vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("i", "<Down>", "<ESC>gji", {})
```

But its not a nice solution because I jump out of insert mode when I press fast...
Is there a solution to this problem ?

Comment: Resist the temptation to stay in Insert mode: http://vimcasts.org/episodes/modal-editing-undo-redo-and-repeat/

Comment: Great video. Just to explain myself a bit more.. I just dive in into each mode and adjust small details that I find.. Like in this video there were talking about short keystrokes... You can also make an undo command more specific with this:

```
keymap("i", "<space>", "<space><c-g>u", opts) --undo per word
keymap("i", "<tab>", "<tab><c-g>u", opts) --undo per tab
keymap("i", "<enter>", "<enter><c-g>u", opts) 
```
This can also safe some time ;)
Of curse I train myself in normal mode. I want to be fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("i", "<Up>", "<C-o>gk", {})

vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("i", "<Down>", "<C-o>gj", {})
```

In insert mode the <kbd>Ctrl o</kbd> allows you to run one key command of Normal mode. Vim automatically switch back to Insert mode right after.

Comment: Amazing, Thx :D

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-) You are are welcome. That being said staying in insert mode for a long time is not what most Vim users are doing. You are doomed to be an exotic user that could make your life difficult ;-)

Comment: Just starting.. give me some time ;)